# Translating perl to python - What does this line do (class variable confusion)

Tags: python, perl

`$self->{DES} ->{$id} = join("\t",@tmp[0 ..7]);`

This line is part of a function inside of a perl class whose constructor is

```
sub new {
    my $class=shift;
    my $self ={};
    bless($self,$class);
    return $self;
}
```

The way I interpret it is that we are storing the id lines as a class variable DES which is a hash whose members are $id:. Is this correct?

I also would like some clarification about the `=~` operator (which seems to always precede a regular expression). As far as I can tell it is basically just the same as in python doing `re.X` where X depends on the flag after the regular expression in perl (such as i). Is this correct?

Comment: How can you translate Perl if you do not know what [the binding operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) is?

Comment: I am learning, never used perl before. I only know python. This translation is my task for December.

Comment: Then the documentation is your friend: http://perldoc.perl.org/

Comment: "How can you translate Perl if you do not know what the binding operator is?" <- One of the problems with researching perl, is it's difficult to perform a google search on things like `$"` and `=~` and `%-`.  Give the guy a bit of a break.  The question wasn't ill formed.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity This is where http://www.symbolhound.com/ comes in handy.

Comment: @Hyperboreus, bookmarked, that's really useful.

Comment: Same, thank you for that link. I was definitely having a very hard time googling things. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity You can do `perldoc -v $"` and `perldoc perlop`. The first place to look should be the documentation. Though I agree, its not as newbie friendly as it could be. I did not mean anything by my comment, except to wonder at how it was at all possible to translate code without knowledge or documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. Perl will automatically create hashes-inside-hashes, sort of like Python's `defaultdict` subclassed to create more defaultdicts. Using regular dict and idiomatic Python, the equivalent assignment would translate as:

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    self.DES = {}

def foo(self, ...):
    self.DES[id_] = "\t".join(tmp[:7])
```

The quoted `new` sub is what Python would do in stock `__new__`:

```
def __new__(cls):
    self = object.__new__(cls)
    return self
```

`bless` is similar to assigning to `self.__class__`, except you don't need to do it in Python because `object.__new__` already creates an object of the correct class. The object is first created as a hash (dict) because in Perl most class objects inherit from hash - unlike Python, where object will typically *contain* a dict rather than inherit from it.

The `=~` operator is equivalent to calling `pattern.search` on an automagically compiled regular expression pattern. You get the `re.X` syntax only if the pattern ends with `/x`. Other options for patterns can be found in the copious [`perlre` man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).